# Devenv.exe with /I and whitespacess

Tags: c++, visual-studio, directx, devenv

I've tried to compile an application with Directx. But this causes an PRJ0030 error for $().
How can I escape critical characters like (,) or blanks. Refering to the cmd I've used ^ but it does not help.

Answer (score 1):

```
AdditionalLibraryDirectories="&quot;$(DIRECTX_ROOT)\Lib\x86&quot;"
```

`&quot` should not be there.  $(DIRECTX_ROOT) requires the macro to be set in a project property sheet.  You are better off spelling it out:

```
AdditionalLibraryDirectories="c:\blah\dx9\Lib\x86"
```

Comment: Unfortunately I need to do it this way, cause we would like to set the path with enviroment variables. Without the &qout; it gives me this compiler line:
/I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (March 2009)"\Include

But the same error occurs.

Comment: Looks about right.  There is however a mis-placed double-quote there, before the \Include.  Check the environment variable value.  You've also mysteriously switched for Lib to Include.

Comment: The lib / include was a copy&paste error, but nevertheless the problem is the same. Indeed I've qouted my enviroment variable, cause I've tried to get it work like this, but even without double-quotes it does not work.

Comment: @Esco: I'm kinda lost right now with copy/paste errors and quotes in random places.  Open the Buildlog.htm file and copy the cl.exe command line you see there into your question so we know what it *really* looks like.

Answer (score 0):

`cmd.exe` unfortunately isn't a proper shell like `bash`, and parsing the command line is up to each individual program. I can't speak for `devenv.exe` but a common convention is to surround troublesome strings with double quotes (`"`).

Comment: I've tried to use the quotes like this:
[...]
AdditionalLibraryDirectories="&quot;$(DIRECTX_ROOT)\Lib\x86&quot;"
[...]
But it does not seem to work. Also double quotes in the variable does not help.